# How to use a path with spaces in the batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a simple Win 10 batch script to open a bunch of folders within Explorer at system startup, however there's a problem with the last command's path containing whitespaces, as instead of opening a new Explorer window as expected, it opens a CMD window with the path as a system command:

```
@ECHO OFF
start C:\Users\Darek\Fallout2
start C:\Users\Darek\Fallout2\data\scripts
start C:\Users\Darek\Pobrane_2
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC"
```

How do I write the last command so it works correctly?

Comment: duplicates: [Can I use the “start” command with spaces in the path?](https://superuser.com/q/239565/241386), [Weird behavior when launching app from CMD with/without start](https://superuser.com/q/758870/241386), [How do I actually open a program from a batch file? All it does is open a command prompt with that file name](https://superuser.com/q/587131/241386)...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue is that the `start` command (built into CMD) has a special way to handle the first parameter with quotation marks, which is to specify an optional title for the created window; without the first set of quotation marks (like the solution below), the `start` command is interpreting the command shown in the question as follows:

1. Create a window with a title of:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC
   ```
2. No information is provided on what to actually start in that window

The solution is to run:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC"

:: # Or more elaborately:
start "Optional Window Title" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC"
```

Comment: Thx., this actually work. Another metchod I just have discovered is to create a non-space including shortcut  and to pass the shortcut name to start command!

Comment: "has a special way to handle the first parameter with quotation marks".  That's... evil.

Comment: @RonJohn that's one of the nasty things left from 16-bit Windows era. There were no long file name support there so if `start` sees a `"` then it assumes that's a window title. It's impossible to fix, so just avoid cmd nowadays and use powershell instead

Answer (score 0):

You can start `explorer.exe` with a path; it will open a new window displaying the specified path. If a non-existing path is given, explorer will default to displaying the user's `My Documents` folder